# send() via blocking socket timed out but the message arrived at the destination thereafter

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, deadlock, p2p

I'm dealing with a distributed "deadlock" situation in a peer-to-peer communication system (written and run in Python 3.5). In this system, each node maintains 2 so-called *inconn* and *outconn* connections with each of its peers. I use select.poll() to perform multiplexing. So sometimes the following deadlock would happen: if two connected peers both trying to send to the other via the *outconn*, the select.poll() loop of each peer is blocking in send() and therefore the other side cannot recv() on the *inconn* connection.

The way I handle this kind of deadlock is to settimeout() on the socket of *outconnn*, which seems working. However, it's interesting that the message seems to be able to arrive at the destination after the socket timed out. Here are the example logs of the two nodes:

**Node A(192.168.56.109)**

> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:05,172] [COOP] Sending ASK_COOP [2016-11-02 11:08:05.**172643**] to 192.168.56.110 for segment 2.
>
> WARNING: [2016-11-02 11:08:06,173] [COOP] Cannot send to 192.168.56.110. Error: timed out
>
> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:06,174] [COOP] Message from 192.168.56.110 is available on 10.
>
> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:06,174] [COOP] Get HEARTBEAT [2016-11-02 11:08:04.**503723**] from 192.168.56.110 for segment 2.

**Node B(192.168.56.110)**

> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:04,503] [COOP] Sending HEARTBEAT [2016-11-02 11:08:04.**503723**] to 192.168.56.109 for segment 2.
>
> WARNING: [2016-11-02 11:08:05,505] [COOP] Cannot send to 192.168.56.109. Error: timed out
>
> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:05,505] [COOP] Message from 192.168.56.109 is available on 11.
>
> INFO: [2016-11-02 11:08:05,505] [COOP] Get ASK_COOP [2016-11-02 11:08:05.**172643**] from 192.168.56.109 for segment 2.

May I know why is that? And by the way, is my way of handling such deadlock a good practice? If not, what is the best practice to avoid such distributed deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the best practice for avoiding this problem is to always use non-blocking I/O.  If your app never blocks inside send() or recv(), then there can be no deadlock (at least, not of the kind you are describing).

Of course, non-blocking I/O brings its own complexities -- in particular, your code needs to be able to handle partial sends and partial receives correctly.  In practice, this means that your app's event loop might look something like this (pseudocode):

```
while true:
   block in select() until at least one socket is ready-for-read (or ready-for write, if you have data you want to send on that socket)

   for each ready-for-read socket:      
      read as many bytes as you can (without blocking) into a FIFO receive buffer that you have associated with that socket
      parse as many complete messages as you can out of the beginning of the FIFO buffer 
      (pop the parsed bytes out of the FIFO when you're done with them)

   for each ready-for-write socket:
      send as many bytes as you can (without blocking) from a FIFO send buffer that you have associated with that socket
      (pop the sent bytes out of the FIFO when you're done with them)
```

In this design, whenever your app has generated new data that it wants to send on a socket, it shouldn't call send() directly; instead it should append that data to the end of the FIFO send buffer you have associated with that socket, and the above event loop will allow the data to be sent as soon as possible (after any sending any data that was already present in the FIFO, of course), *without ever blocking the event loop from performing any other duties it might have*.

In the worst case (a very slow TCP connection that you want to send a lot of data over) the FIFO might become large (using extra memory), but it will never "deadlock".